# How to prove $\frac{\arccos\frac{\sqrt{3}}{6}}{\pi}$ is not a rational number?

Tags: trigonometry, rational-numbers

The number:
$$\frac{\arccos\frac{\sqrt{3}}{6}}{\pi}$$
How to prove it's not a rational number?

Comment: One line of attack you could try: $\frac{x}{\pi}$ is rational iff $\cos nx=1$ for some integer $n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let
$$r=\dfrac{\arccos\dfrac{\sqrt3}6}\pi,$$
then
$$\pi r=\arccos\left(\dfrac13\cos\dfrac\pi6\right),$$
$$3\cos\pi r=\cos\dfrac\pi6,$$
$$\dfrac\pi6=2\pi n\pm\arccos(3\cos\pi r),$$
$$\dfrac\pi6=2\pi n\pm(4\pi^3r^3-3\pi r),$$
$$1=12n\pm(24\pi^2r^3-18r),$$
$$\pi^2=\frac{18r\pm(1-12n)}{24r^3},\text{ where }n\in\mathbb N.$$

$\pi^2$ isn't rational, so $r$ **isn't rational**.